# WAMP to XAMPP WordPress transfer

Tags: xampp, localhost, wamp, wordpress

I want to transfer a WordPress site from a wamp localhost to xampp localhost. Using the Tools > Export, I saved the WordPress content to an XML file. I did not create a similar backup of the MySQL databases (and won't be able to do so now) but have all the files from wamp.

How can I make this transfer without having to install a new version of WordPress? There are important settings in widgets and plugins that I need preserved. I am looking to place the relevant wamp and WordPress files in the correct xampp and WordPress folders.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The settings are stored in the database. So if you can't make a backup of that, you won't be able to restore it with the old settings intact. There's no need to even use export anyway, just copy and paste the files and change the database settings.

Comment: So there is no way to manually overwrite files to MySQL? Is there a way to access the stored code from the widgets?

Comment: The code is stored in the database. Do you have access to the database? There are plugins available that can save widget data, eg: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-settings-importexport/.

Comment: No, I no longer have access to the phpMyAdmin login. I have all the phpMyAdmin/MySQL files and folders. Is there anyway I can access the database?